# PHP : Read GMAIL Email with imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

here's my problem: I have a mailbox where came from 2 types of email:

1) e-mail with plain text
2) email, I think, base64-encoded text / html

I have a simple page in php that goes to read this email box, and prints out an HTML table with some information of each email

I recognize the two types of email from the object of the email, in the first case I have no problems, while in the second i have a problem

i read the "body" of the mail of the first type in this way (and I have no problem, I can print the contents of the email as plain text) :

```
$id = imap_uid($stream ,$email_id);
$message = imap_qprint(imap_body($stream, $email_id,FT_PEEK));
```

but in the second case it does not work this way, and I have tried the following

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"");
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"0");
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"1");
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"1.1");
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"1.2");
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,"2");
echo "*".base64_decode($message)."*";
echo "*".imap_base64($message)."*";
```

but I have no result

Comment: Your understanding of MIME structure is clearly inadequate.  There is no way to predict which body part will be a "main part" (which isn't well-defined in the first place anyway) without inspecting the message's MIME structure, separately for each message.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply: D
how should I proceed then in your opinion?
the email that I can not read contains images and text, and is generated by Windows SBS

Comment: I can not read the contents as plain text omitting images?

Comment: For this message, and every other message you process, you need to look at the purpose of each part (if it's a multipart in the first place) and then decide which part(s) you want to display, if any.  I cannot predict what criteria exactly you want to use.

Comment: One common approach is to let the user specify a preference for `text/plain` or `text/html` and display whichever of these you find at the top level (assuming you have a `multipart/alternative` or similar, although the semantics are blurry -- many senders will use `multipart/related` or `multipart/mixed` for the same purpose), then display the other parts as "attachments".

Comment: I do not display all the contents of the mail, but only parts

The email has the same format, just change a few words